# Firestore: difference between set() and add()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the difference between `set()` and `add()` in Firestore?

I use the `set()` to add documents to my collection. But I am unable to use `add()` or understand `add()` from docs.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Since you didn't specify, I'm going to assume you mean [set() on DocumentReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/DocumentReference#set), and [add() on CollectionReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/CollectionReference#add).

When you use `set()` on a `DocumentReference`, you're putting data into a document that you're **already identified** by some unique id.  (Otherwise, you wouldn't already have a `DocumentReference` object!) As it says in the docs, "If the document does not yet exist, it will be created."  If the document already exists, you're either replacing or merging new data into it.

When you use `add()` on a CollectionReference, you're unconditionally creating a new document in a collection, and that new document will have a **unique id** assigned to it. The data you pass will become the contents of the new document.

Comment: Thank you @Doug for this short of clarification.

Answer (score 11):

`set()` create or overwrite a single document && you have the option to specify an ID for the document to create

`add()` auto generate doc and give it ID automatically

More info - official docs : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 0):

add() is called on the collection ref, thus creating a new document.

set() is called on a document ref, thus if the document with same ref already exist, it would be overwritten; otherwise a new document is created.