# Firestore cloud new document created everytime when code runs

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever the location is sent to Firestore cloud from the app it creates a new document every time. I just want the change to occur in the document field which has changed.

Here's my the code:-

```
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if( grantResults.length > 0  && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60 , 0,locationListener);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, location.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            db.collection("Location")
                    .add(location)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            Log.d("Info", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w("Info", "Error adding document", e);
                        }
                    }); ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is creating a new document because you are using [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#add(java.lang.Object)):

> `public Task<DocumentReference> add (Object pojo)`
>
> Adds a new document to this collection with the specified POJO as contents, assigning it a document ID automatically.

You need to use [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#set(java.lang.Object)) instead:

```
db.collection("cities").document("Locations")
    .set(location)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
```

check this also:

[Firestore: set() & add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474522/firestore-set-add)

Comment: Thanks @Peter. One more question if i am using set do i need have to create  document manually ?

Comment: you can create the document in the code, no need to write it in the console (like in the answer)