# Is it possible to receive duplicate IDs with Firebase .doc()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

As specified in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc), `.doc()` creates a unique ID.

I create new documents for Firestore the following way (note that `session.docId` should be equal to the actual document ID and I am using AngularFire syntax):

```
const id = db.createId();
const session = { docId: id, name: "test" };
this.db.collection("sessions").doc(id).set(session);
```

Does `.doc()` guarantee that the above workflow will always work (meaning that `id` will always be unique)?
Let's assume I have an array full of sessions (e.g. 10000 items) - I iterate over this array and create a session document for each item the way I specified it above. Considering the asynchronous nature of Javascript, I am very sceptical if this might produce a duplicate ID at some point (although very unlikely due to the length etc. of the `docId`). Or does `.doc()` "reserve" the ID for a limited amount of time?

I am aware that I could also create a new document via `.add()` and update the `docId` afterwards via `.set()`, but this method would need 2 write operations and would also be way slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`doc()` always generates a DocumentReference with random ID *immediately* on the client app (not asynchronously) that is virtually guaranteed to be unique.  The chance of collision between two IDs is astronomically low.  It's effectively the same thing as calling `add()`, except it is not actually creating the document at the same time.

Note that `doc()` doesn't return the string ID directly - it returns a DocumentReference that contains the ID.

See also:

- [Firestore: Are ids unique in the collection or globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618719/firestore-are-ids-unique-in-the-collection-or-globally)

If for some reason you do not trust this method of generating IDs, you are free to generate them yourself somehow.  It's just a string.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, I was not aware of the immediate client side creation of the DocumentReference.

Comment: If any method does not return a promise, then it is synchronous.  The promise tells you that something is async, and the absence of a Promise is a clear signal that the work happens immediately.